# Compress a list of page references

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I'm looking for a pure (La)TeX solution (alas, no LuaTeX) for compressing a list of page references (given with `\pageref`) like `cite.sty` does with citations; that is "Compress lists of three or more consecutive numbers to one number range." The numbers are already sorted and can have up to four digits. Basically what MakeIndex does but in TeX.

Input would be like `\pageref{foo}, \pageref{bar}, \pageref{foobar}, \pageref{quax}` (where the delimiter can be choosen as needed) and the output should be something like "1, 2--4".

Comment: Have you try the package cleveref ?

Comment: @projetmbc: Not yet. But it seems to deal only with `\ref`, not `\pageref`.

Comment: @projetmbc: The latest version does; see below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version **(V0.18)** of `cleveref` includes `\cpageref` and `\cpagerefrange` which can be used to refer to page ranges as well.    It is not yet on CTAN, so for the test below I obtained it from [Toby Cubitt's site](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.php#cleveref-download):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}% load last

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\section{One-One}\label{One-One}
\lipsum[1-4]\label{One-Two}

\chapter{Two}
\section{Two-One}\label{Two-One}
\section{Two-Two}\label{Two-Two}
\section{Two-Three}\label{Two-Three}

\chapter{Three}
\section{Three-One}\label{Three-One}
\lipsum[1-9]

\newpage
Section One-One is on Page~\pageref{One-One}\par
Section One-Two is on Page~\pageref{One-Two}\par
Section Two-One is on Page~\pageref{Two-One}\par
Section Two-Two is on Page~\pageref{Two-Two}\par
Section Two-Three is on Page~\pageref{Two-Three}\par
Section Three-One is on Page~\pageref{Three-One}\par


\bigskip
Using the \textbf{cleveref package (V0.18)}:\par
\bigskip
See \cpageref{One-One,One-Two,Three-One}\par
See \cpageref{One-One,One-Two,Two-One,Two-Two,Three-One}\par
See \cpagerefrange{One-One}{Three-One}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This has not turned out as pretty as I initially hoped, but it seems to work. It takes a list of integers and it compacts them as you described. The code should be pretty self-explanatory, I can't help but feel it should be possible to do it much shorter, but hey.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\dotlessi\i
\newcount\last
\def\range#1{%
  \last 0\relax
  \def\temp{}
  \def\first{}
  \@for\i:=#1\do{%
    \ifnum\the\last=0%start
      \edef\temp{\i}%
    \else%
      \advance\last 1\relax%
      \ifnum\last=\i%
        \ifx\first\empty%
          \let\@temp\temp%
          \edef\temp{\@temp--}%
          \def\first{x}%
        \else%
        \fi%
      \else%
        \ifx\first\empty%
          \let\@temp\temp%
          \let\j\i%
          \edef\temp{\@temp,\j}
        \else%
          \advance\last -1\relax%
          \let\@temp\temp%
          \let\j\i%
          \edef\temp{\@temp\the\last,\j}%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    \last \i\relax%
  }%
  [\temp]%
}
\makeatother
\let\i\dotlessi
\begin{document}
\noindent
Some test ranges\\
\range{1,2,3,4,7}\\
\range{1,3,5,7}\\
\range{1,3,4,5,7}\\
\range{}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: picture showing ranges]

PS: what happened to the tex.sx image uploading? :(

Comment: [image uploading] See imgur.com: "Emergency maintenance
We're currently expirencing issues with uploading and viewing some images, and are working on correcting them now. Please check back soon for updates."

Comment: I've moved the `\newcount` command outside the definition of `\range`: you were allocating a new counter for each call of `\range`.

Comment: Nice. Can this be improved wit LaTeX3 and/or eTeX?